# Using the await keyword to mimic sychronous programming

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

This is how I do ajax calls:

```js
$(document).on('click','#doit',clicked)
clicked = function() {
  var local = {}
  local.type = 'post'
  local.dataType = 'json'
  local.data = {}
  local.data.myid = 1234
  var promise = $.ajax('myPage.cfm',local)
  promise.done(done)
  promise.fail(fail)

  function done(response) {
  }

  function fail(xhr,status,response) {
    $('body').html(xhr.responseText)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In this example, `done` and `fail` are callbacks.
But I read in [this article](https://derickbailey.com/2017/04/18/you-need-es7s-async-functions-heres-why/?imm_mid=0f1021&cmp=em-web-na-na-newsltr_20170419) of a new keyword called await.

Q: Am I reading this right, that I no longer have to refer to callbacks and promises? That I can just write straight synchronous code the way I used to? How can I rewrite the above example using the await keyword?

Comment: Actually, writing code that *either* goes to a `done` part when successful, *or* goes to a `fail` part when there is an exception, is quite hard to write in a synchronous manner.

Comment: You don't *have to* use `async`/`await` (especially when wanting to support older browser). Writing plain promise code is just fine.

Comment: What if I'm willing to ignore the `fail` and use try/catch it instead?

Comment: The article linked to goes over how to translate code from promises to async/await. Is there something there you don't understand? The answer to your first two questions in your question is no, you do need to make adjustments in order to use async/await. For instance, your async functions need to return a promise and the calling code needs to use the await keyword.

Comment: Not "synchronous", but "sequential". `await` allows you to write asynchronous code in a *sequential* way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
init()
async function init() {
 var form = {}
 form.type = 'post'
 form.dataType = 'json'
 form.data = {}
 form.data.myid = 1234
 try {
  var ok=true
  var promise = await $.ajax('myPage.cfm',form)
 } catch(xhr) {
  console.log(xhr.responseText)
  ok=false
 }
 if (ok) {
  console.log(promise)
 }
}
```